Normalization of time-series data before computing Dynamic Time Warping (DTW)
I am interested in a proper normalization method of my time-series data before computing the dynamic time warping (DTW) distance.
Situation:
I have four time series (colored in two different green tones, purple, and red) that are based on sliding window Pearson correlations. This means that every data point of these graphs reflects a Pearson correlation coefficient.
Moreover, I have a sliding window result of measurement x (the blue time series). Just for plotting, I have normalized this time series to an interval from 0 to 1. The real value range of this time series is more like ~1.1 to ~1.8.
As can be seen, the purple and red time series seem to converge with the blue time series. My aim is to show (in a quantitative manner) that the distance between the purple/red time series with the blue time series is smaller (or closer) than the distances from the two green time series to the blue one.
I didn't want to use correlation or cross-correlation because the relationship is non-linear or not stable across time. Therefore, I thought about applying DTW here.
Eamonn Keogh pointed out that the z-score normalization is appropriate or even needed in ~99% of cases before applying DTW. (For example, see here: https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf)
Question: Would it be fine to simply apply the z-score normalization to each time-series, both on the dynamic (sliding window) Pearson correlation time series and on the measurement x (blue colored) time series?
Or should I only normalize the blue time series to an interval of [-1, 1], namely the theoretical interval of the Pearson correlation? I feel confused and have no idea what is reasonable here, also given the fact that the blue time series is non-stationary.

